# Geolocation api: how to know if the user clicked on close or block button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, geolocation

I am using geolocation api to know the customer's location. 1)If the customer select on share location I send the latitude and longitude to another page using ajax to build the result page which contains data for their location. 
2) If the customer don't want share the location I want to send other data using ajax.

```
 <script>
 window.onload = function() {

 var startPos;

  var geoSuccess = function(position) {
  startPos = position;
  var x= startPos.coords.latitude;
  var y= startPos.coords.longitude;
 $.post("<?php echo $config['SiteGlobalPath']; ?>setsession.php", {lat:x, lon:y}).done(function (data){
 window.location.href="<?php echo $config['SiteGlobalPath']; ?>";});
 };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);

};

</script>
```

how to know if the customer didn't click on the share location. and instead clicked on the block or close button ( so I could buil another query instead using their location).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a second optional function to be called when an error occours or the user denies the location request.

```
var geoError = function(code, message) {
    alert(code + message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
```

More details can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError